# Error converting data type NVarchar into int

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm inserting data in two tables at once...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inserttwo
(
     @BookID int,
     @BookName nvarchar(50),
     @DateIssue datetime,
     @ReturnDate datetime,
     @PersonID int
)
AS
    INSERT INTO tblReturn(BookID, BookName, DateIssue, ReturnDate, PersonID)
    VALUES(@BookID, @BookName, @DateIssue, @ReturnDate, @PersonID)

    INSERT INTO tblIssue(BookID, BookName, DateIssue, ReturnDate, PersonID)
    VALUES(@BookID, @BookName, @DateIssue, @ReturnDate, @PersonID)
```

then I'm updating and deleting these tables by stored procedure...

Delete query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Issuedelete]
(@BookID int)
AS
    DELETE FROM tblIssue
    WHERE BookID = @BookID
```

Update query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IssueUpdate]
   (@BookID int,
    @BookName nvarchar(50),
    @DateIssue datetime,
    @ReturnDate datetime,
    @PersonID int)
AS
    UPDATE tblIssue
    SET [BookID]     = @BookID , 
        [BookName]   = @BookName,
        [DateIssue]  = @DateIssue,
        [ReturnDate] = @ReturnDate,
        [PersonID]   = @PersonID
    WHERE BookID = @BookID
```

C# code to delete from tblIssue:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Issuedelete", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", ComBox1BookID.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        storedproc();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

C# code to update tblIssue:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IssueUpdate", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", ComBox1BookID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookName", ComBox2BName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateIssue", IssueDate.Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReturnDate", ReturnDate.Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", CBox3PerID.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        storedproc();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SqlError" + ex);
    }
}
```

After compiling, I get an error

> Can't convert datatype into int

I tried other ways by changing the parameters with OleDB and SqlDbType... But it's not deleting and updating records... And also having same problem when I'm updating and deleting into tblReturn... Please, help me??? :(

Comment: So do you get an error during compile time or when you run the application?

Comment: @dotnetom when i run n update my record it's giving an error...

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s I changed the AddWithValue() with cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int); I get an error : 'string input wasn't correct format'.

Comment: @Warda: are you trying to set the `int` value to something that's not really an  `int` then??

Comment: @marc_s What int value???...  Seriously, my muind flipped... I dont know where I'm doing mistake???

Comment: @Warda: your `@BookId` is an int - but you seem to want to set it to something else ...

Comment: @marc_s no.. I set it as int ...

Comment: @marc_s thanks ton!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending text values to integer and datetime parameters, Change your update button click event code to

```
        private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IssueUpdate", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", Convert.ToInt32(ComBox1BookID.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookName", ComBox2BName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateIssue", IssueDate.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReturnDate", ReturnDate.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID",Convert.ToInt32(CBox3PerID.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                storedproc();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SqlError" + ex);

            }
        }
```

**Update**
Remove this line after *set* in your update stored procedure

> [BookID] =@BookID ,

if its a identity column, it will throw exception on updating it.

**Update 2**

Try this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ComBox1BookID.Text);`
if you are adding parameters with add function

Comment: @Rahul, i was just about to write, check the updated solution.

Comment: As a side note (for OP and any one else reading this comment), please stop using `AddWithValue()` as it has problem infering the type which may incur performance penalty as well as wrong outcome. Rather use `cmd.Parameters.Add()`

Comment: @Rahul No, it's not acception this , cmd.Parameters.Add()

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla not giving any error... but , it is not updating and deleting...

Comment: @Warda, check my updated solution. Remove `[BookID] =  @BookID ,` from your update stored procedure.

Comment: @Warda, similarily in your delete button click, cast your ComBox1BookID.Text into int as `Convert.ToInt32(ComBox1BookID.Text)`

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla I removed it... still not updating records... :(

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla I changed the code as u said... Convert.ToInt32(ComBox1BookID.Text) .. It's giving an error 'String isn't in correct format'.

Comment: @ShaminderSAujia I changed the AddWithValue() with cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int); I get an error : 'string input wasn't correct format'.

Comment: @Warda asign value to the '@BookID' parameter

Comment: @Warda try this: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ComBox1BookID.Text);`

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla I tried.. error is same as before... 'String input wasn't in a correct format'.... :(

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla problem I was doing mistake... I added One more column name ID n use in update and delete query... with Where clause.       I need only change to Convert the columns... . :) Thanks ton!!!